# Extrema using Lagrange Multiplier

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima

Let $f(\textbf{x})=\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{a_j}{x_j}$, determine its extrema on the set $$S=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n|\prod_{j=1}^n x_j=C\}$$

The answer is here http://math.nyu.edu/student_resources/wwiki/index.php/Advanced_Calculus:_1998_January:_Problem_1. However, I don't get the step from" Dividing $i\neq k$, we get $-\frac{a_i}{x_i}\frac{1}{\prod^n_{j\neq i}x_j}=-\frac{a_k}{x_k}\frac{1}{\prod^n_{j\neq k}x_k}$. Can someone explain this a little bit. Thanks. Or is there an easier way to go from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have the system of $n$ equations written in vector form
$$\left(-\frac{a_1}{x_1^2},\cdots,-\frac{a_n}{x_n^2}\right)=\lambda\left(\prod_{j\neq1}x_j,\cdots,\prod_{j\neq n}x_j\right)$$
In the step you are talking about, they have divided by the product on the RHS of the equations to give
$$-\frac{a_i}{x_i^2}\frac{1}{\prod_{j\neq i}x_j}=\lambda$$
for $i=1,\cdots,n$. The RHS is common to all the equations, so we can equate all the LHS as well. So for $i\neq k$ we arrive at
$$-\frac{a_i}{x_i^2}\frac{1}{\prod_{j\neq i}x_j}=-\frac{a_k}{x_k^2}\frac{1}{\prod_{j\neq k}x_j}$$
We can write this as 
$$\frac{a_i}{x_i}\frac{1}{\prod_{j=1}^n x_j}=\frac{a_k}{x_k}\frac{1}{\prod_{j=1}^n x_j}$$
which further gives
$$\frac{a_i}{x_i}=\frac{a_k}{x_k}$$
Has this answered your question?

Comment: Thanks so mmuch, that explained well enough

Comment: Wow, thats an easy observation that I failed to observe, bit embrassing :(